# How to set page level variables in adobe DTM?

Tags: javascript, adobe-analytics

I have used the adobe analytics for the tracking purpose in my website, but unfortunately I couldn't able to set the variables definition to that.

My code:

```
var z = new Object();
z.abc = true;
z.def.ghi = true
```

I am defining a variable like the above format, but I am unable to set it. Any help on this.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a checkbox in script editor which gives you the option to run the code globally. That will do it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set z.def.ghi unless you first define z.def as an object.  For example:

```
var z = new Object();
z.abc = true;
z.def = {};
z.def.ghi = true
```